# How do I clear a custom log format?

Tags: git, rake-task, git-log

We have a utility rake script used by multiple devs in our department. Part of the script involves grabbing some data from git, and it's done by running `git log` and parsing the results. In order to get around a problem where a dev might have a custom log format configured, we were using `--pretty=''` to clear formats.

This worked with git 1.9.3, but recently I updated to git 2.2.1 and it doesn't work the same way at all.

Ultimately the solution is going to be using something like [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) to get the data we need instead of parsing log output, but in the short term, is there an option to add to `git log` to clear custom formats set by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_formatting) notes that:

> When omitted, the format defaults to `medium`.

so simply set it explicity to `medium` to override individual `format.pretty` settings.